# homebrew t match atu issues

Tags: hf, antenna-system, antenna-tuner

my homemade tmatch atu is ok on 80+40m but seems too have too mutch inductance on the bands above 40m,it has a 50mm/20cm roller coaster,i have a 40m doublet+ 4-1 balun+ common mode choke fitted in the atu,any way i can make it match 20 and up?,i wind the inductor to min but i guess all the interconnecting wires have too mutch L?.73

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to the site! What tools do you have to measure inductance or complex impedance? Please add that info to your post instead of the comments... thank you!

Comment: How is the inductor connected? Can you draw or link to a circuit diagram showing that part in detail? And have you tried testing it with a 50 ohm dummy load, is the SWR low on all bands, rising as you reduce either C or the L?

Comment: Oh also add pictures (link to Imgur if you don't have enough reputation to add them yourself)